# Javascript - How to not overwrite a var when used in a function passed as parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a for loop and inside it a var named path, I use this var in a function that I pass as parameter of another function, it's look like this :

```
for( ... ){
  var path = ...;
  $("<button>").html(path).click(function(){ ...want to use path here... }).appendTo(...);
}
```

The problem is that path is overwritten at each new turn of the for loop, my full function look like this :

```
this.goTo = function(path){
    that.path = path;
    that.files = [];
    that.selectedFiles = [];

    //Display path
    that.pathDiv.empty();
    var dirs = that.path.split("/");
    if(dirs.length > 1 && dirs[dirs.length-1].length == 0){
        dirs.splice(dirs.length-1, 1);
    }
    for(var d in dirs){
        var path = "/";
        for(var i=0;i<d;i++){
            if(dirs[i].length > 0){
                path += dirs[i] + "/";
            }
        }
        var name = "/";
        if(dirs[d].length > 0){
            path += dirs[d] + "/";
            name = dirs[d];
        }
        that.pathDiv.append($("<button>").html(name).click(function(){ console.log(path); that.goTo(path); }));
    }

    that.directoryContent.empty();
    serverUI.emit("getDirectoryContent", {path: that.path});
}
```

I can't use the onClick attribute in my html tag because I need to access to the object which triggered the function (that), any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach the path as an attribute on the element itself, like so.

```
for( ... ){
  var path = ...;
  $("<button>").attr("path",path).html(path).click(function(){  
     $(this).attr("path")  // use it like this.
 ...want to use path here... }).appendTo(...);
}
```